# Export BeautifulSoup scraping results to CSV; scrape + include image values in column

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

For this project, I am scraping data from a database and attempting to export this data to a spreadsheet for further analysis.

While my code seems mostly to work well, when it comes to the last bit--exporting to CSV--I am having no luck. This question has been asked a few times, however it seems the answers were geared towards different approaches, and I didn't have any luck adapting their answers.

My code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
url1 = "http://www.elections.ca/WPAPPS/WPR/EN/NC?province=-1&distyear=2013&district=-1&party=-1&pageno="
url2 = "&totalpages=55&totalcount=1368&secondaryaction=prev25"

date1 = []
date2 = []
date3 = []
party=[]
riding=[]
candidate=[]
winning=[]
number=[]

for i in range(1, 56):
    r  = requests.get(url1 + str(i) + url2)
    data = r.text
    cat = BeautifulSoup(data)
    links = []
    for link in cat.find_all('a', href=re.compile('selectedid=')):
        links.append("http://www.elections.ca" + link.get('href'))  
    for link in links:
        r  = requests.get(link)
        data = r.text
        cat = BeautifulSoup(data)
        date1.append(cat.find_all('span')[2].contents)
        date2.append(cat.find_all('span')[3].contents)
        date3.append(cat.find_all('span')[5].contents)
        party.append(re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find("legend").contents[2]).strip())
        riding.append(re.sub("[\n\r/]", "",  cat.find_all('div', class_="group")[2].contents[2]).strip())  
        cs= cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="name/1")        
        elected=[]
        for c in cs:
            elected.append(c.contents[0].strip())
        number.append(len(elected))
        candidate.append(elected)
        winning.append(cs[0].contents[0].strip())


import csv

file = ""

for i in range(0,len(date1)):
    file = [file,date1[i],date2[i],date3[i],party[i],riding[i],"\n"]

with open ('filename.csv','rb') as file:
   writer=csv.writer(file)
   for row in file:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

Really--any tips would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks a lot.

*PART 2: Another question: I previously thought that finding the winning candidate in the table could be simplified by just always selecting the first name that appears in the table, as I thought the "winners" always appeared first. However, this is not the case. 
Whether or not a candidate was elected is stored in the form of a picture in the first column. How would I scrape this and store it in a spreadsheet?
It's located under < td headers > as:

```
< img src="/WPAPPS/WPR/Content/Images/selected_box.gif" alt="contestant won this nomination contest" >
```

I had an idea for attempting some sort of Boolean sorting measure, but I am unsure of how to implement. Thanks a lot.*
UPDATE: This question is now a separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771874/scraping-add-data-stored-as-a-picture-to-csv-file-in-python-3-5).

Comment: Note, you currently have `open('filename.csv','rb')`, you should open the file for writing as `open('filename.csv','wb')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should correctly export your data to a CSV file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import csv


url = "http://www.elections.ca/WPAPPS/WPR/EN/NC?province=-1&distyear=2013&district=-1&party=-1&pageno={}&totalpages=55&totalcount=1368&secondaryaction=prev25"
rows = []

for i in range(1, 56):
    print(i)
    r  = requests.get(url.format(i))
    data = r.text
    cat = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    links = []

    for link in cat.find_all('a', href=re.compile('selectedid=')):
        links.append("http://www.elections.ca" + link.get('href'))  

    for link in links:
        r  = requests.get(link)
        data = r.text
        cat = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        lspans = cat.find_all('span')
        cs = cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="name/1")        
        elected = []

        for c in cs:
            elected.append(c.contents[0].strip())

        rows.append([
            lspans[2].contents[0], 
            lspans[3].contents[0], 
            lspans[5].contents[0],
            re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find("legend").contents[2]).strip(),
            re.sub("[\n\r/]", "",  cat.find_all('div', class_="group")[2].contents[2]).strip().encode('latin-1'),
            len(elected),
            cs[0].contents[0].strip().encode('latin-1')
            ])

with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
   csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
   csv_output.writerows(rows)
```

Giving you the following kind of output in your CSV file:

```
"September 17, 2016","September 13, 2016","September 17, 2016",Liberal,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,1,Stanley Sakamoto
"June 25, 2016","May 12, 2016","June 25, 2016",Conservative,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,6,Brian Benoit
"September 28, 2015","September 28, 2015","September 28, 2015",Liberal,Cowichan--Malahat--Langford,1,Luke Krayenhoff
```

There is no need to build up lots of separate lists for each column of your data, it is easier just to build a list of `rows` directly. This can then easily be written to a CSV in one go (or written a row at a time as your are gathering the data).

Comment: Thank you! Worked very well.
I should have mentioned that I am working with 3.5, so I changed // open('filename.csv', 'wb') // to // ('filename.csv', 'w') // to remedy a type error I was getting. Really appreciate the response!

Comment: Any ideas on Part 2, anyone? Would that be more appropriate for a separate thread?

Comment: For Python 3, you should also use `newline=''` to open the file, I have updated the script. A separate question might work better, I suggest you reduce the problem to the bare minimum number of lines of code.

Comment: Thanks again! 

Update: added my other question as a separate post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771874/scraping-add-data-stored-as-a-picture-to-csv-file-in-python-3-5)